# how is the upi transaction id generated

Tags: java, android, spring, upi

I want to generate a UPI transaction Id on server side . which will be unique (obviously). i am using Spring boot as server side technology and Mongodb as database.

- Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/create-payment-method :

> Important: The transaction reference ID is mandatory and must be
>   unique for every request. This could be order number,
>   subscription number, Bill ID, booking ID, insurance renewal 
>   reference, etc.

So it is just a reference to your system.   Presumably if someone is buying something from you, you are keeping track of it in some Order table or something in MongoDb, for which you are using a unique (possibly auto-generated) Integer primary key, so just use that.